# How to select a record on a Test Page

Tags: dynamics-business-central, microsoft-dynamics-nav

I'm trying to simulate an user, selecting a single record on a list page (i.e. Item List). This is for testing a procedure, which opens said list page, waiting for user input and, if the user presses Ok, adds the selected lines from the list page as lines to a document (i.e. Purchase Line/Purchase Header)

```
    [Test]
    [HandlerFunctions('ItemListOkModalPageHandler')]
    procedure TestAddItemLineItemList()
    var
        LRec_PurchaseHeader: Record "Purchase Header";
        LRec_PurchaseLine: Record "Purchase Line";
        LC_PageHelper: Codeunit "Page Helper";
    begin
        //[GIVEN] given
        CreatePurchaseOrder(LRec_PurchaseHeader);
        LRec_PurchaseLine.SetRange("Document Type", LRec_PurchaseHeader."Document Type");
        LRec_PurchaseLine.SetRange("Document No.", LRec_PurchaseHeader."No.");
        LRec_PurchaseLine.SetRange(Type, "Purchase Line Type"::Item);
        GC_LibraryAssert.RecordIsEmpty(LRec_PurchaseLine);
        //[WHEN] when
        LC_PageHelper.AddMultiplePurchaseLines(LRec_PurchaseHeader);
        //[THEN] then
        GC_LibraryAssert.RecordCount(LRec_PurchaseLine, 1);  // error happens here
    end;

    [ModalPageHandler]
    procedure ItemListOkModalPageHandler(var PTP_ItemList: TestPage "Item List");
    begin
        PTP_ItemList.First();
        PTP_ItemList.OK().Invoke();
    end;
```

When trying to do it this way, I get the following error message:

```
Error:
        Assert.RecordCount failed. Expected number of Purchase Line entries: 1. Actual: 0.
```

Any suggestions, what am I doing wrong?

Edit: Code of Procedure AddMultiplePurchaseLines

```
procedure AddMultiplePurchaseLines(PRec_PurchaseHeader: Record "Purchase Header")
    var
        LRec_Item: Record Item;
        LP_ItemList: Page "Item List";
    begin
        PRec_PurchaseHeader.TestField(Status, "Purchase Document Status"::Open);
        if GuiAllowed then begin
            LP_ItemList.LookupMode(true);
            if LP_ItemList.RunModal() = Action::LookupOK then begin
                LRec_Item.SetFilter("No.", LP_ItemList.GetSelectionFilter());
                AddPurchaseOrderItemLines(PRec_PurchaseHeader, LRec_Item);
            end;
        end;
    end;
```

Comment: Can you please share the code of the `AddMultiplePurchaseLines` procedure?

Comment: Could you add the code for `AddPurchaseOrderItemLines` as well?

Answer (score 0):

The first issue you need to resolve is that activating `LookupMode` on a `Page` changes the returned value of `RunModal`.

This means that in `AddMultiplePurchaseLines` you must change it to:

```
if LP_ItemList.RunModal() = Action::LookupOK then begin
```

Secondly the call to `Expand` in `ItemListOkModalPageHandler` does not do anything. All it does is expand the tree structure (if it exists).

Comment: Thanks for pointing at the problem with the return value of the RunModal procedure.
However, it does not fix the problem with selecting the records for the test case.